# Render row based on the row instance in mat-table in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

So, if the row.id has value(say: id_1313) I want to add a click event to mat-row else I need to simply display the mat-row.

I'll provide a sample code of what I actually did

`app.component.html`

```
<table
   mat-table
   [dataSource]="dataSource"
   width="100%"
 >

 <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          Date
     </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.date }}</td>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
      <div
         *ngIf="
         row.id;
         then hasId;
         else notHasId
         "
        ></div>
       <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr
          #hasId
          mat-row
          (click)="hasId()"
          *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        ></tr>
        <tr
          #notHasId
          mat-row
          *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        ></tr>
  </ng-container>
```

I know the approach I tried is not gonna work, any ideas to do changes only on mat-row. I don't want to use *ngIf for each column value in the ng -container

**EDIT**

I found the answer after some research. We can enable the click method using ternary operator. The demo code is below.

```html
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr
   mat-row
   *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
   (click)="row.id != null ? displayDetails(row) : null"
></tr>
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to add the `(click)` to all of the rows and then simply have the function `return;` if the row has no id?

Comment: I have solution for that, but I want to know is there a way to solve it like this?

Comment: you can use also `(click)="row.id!=null && displayDetails(row)"`. Rememeber that Javascrip is "short circuit avaluation" (If first condition is not fullfilled, don't execute the second one)

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you, this improves the readability as well.